# Find a cauchy sequence that converges outside of space

Tags: calculus, general-topology, metric-spaces

Let $h$ be the space of infinite sequences $x=(x_1,x_2,...,x_n,...)$ with a finite number of elements that are not zero.

The metric defined on $h$ is $d(x,y) = \sup_{n \in \mathbb N}|x_n-y_n|$.

Prove that this space is separable but not complete.

**Terminology**: separable means that there is $h' \subset h$ such that $h'$ is countable and that every $A \subset h$ contains at least one element from $h'$. $h'$ is dense and countable.

Complete space means that every cauchy sequence in this space converges to an element of this space.

We were asked to prove that this space is not complete, so we want to find a cauchy sequence $\{x_n\}$ such that $x_n \in h$ for all $n$, but $\lim_{n \to \infty} x_n \notin h$.

We also want to find a dense countable subset.

**What I did:**
I'm trying to come up with countable subsets that are dense. It has to be something with rational numbers, since that set is countable and dense in $\mathbb R$.

I was thinking maybe the set of sequences of only rational numbers, or sequences whos sum is rational, but those sets are not countable.

I'm also completely stumped on the cauchy sequence bit. Having trouble finding a cauchy sequence that converges outside $h$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're on the right track about the countable dense subset. To have a more focused question in mind, perhaps ask this: How would you approximate (using a sequence involving finitely many rational numbers) the point $(\pi, e, \sqrt{2}, 0, \sqrt{3}, 0, 0, \dots)$? If you can deal with this one, you should be able to deal with anything. Remember that a countable union of countable sets is still countable.

---

For the Cauchy sequence that doesn't converge, use the fact that the support must be finite. For example, take a sequence like

\begin{align*}
&\left(1, 0, 0, \dots\right) \\
&\left(1, \frac 1 2, 0, \dots \right) \\
& \left(1, \frac 1 2, \frac 1 4, 0, \dots\right) \\
\end{align*}

Do you see why this is a Cauchy sequence? Now it's "obvious" what the candidate limit should be and why it's not in the space. Of course, there's still some work that needs to be done to justify that there's no limit in the given space - this isn't quite enough.

Comment: @OriaGruber You're thinking harder than is necessary (and that's not a sequence of rational numbers, after all). Perhaps try $2, 2.7, 2.71, ...$. But the method isn't the important part - just take as a black box that you can approximate anything by a rational. If you can approximate $e$ and $\pi$ separately, can you approximate the sequence $(e, \pi, 0, 0, \dots)$?

Comment: I'm sorry this is still rather new to me. I understand your approximation, and $\pi$ would be $3,3.1,3.14$ etc. But how does that help with the dense part? Not every open subset of $h$ contains a sequence that has $\pi$ as element.

Comment: @OriaGruber The exact approximation you use is completely inconsequential. What I'm asking is: If you can approximate a real number $r$ with rationals, can you think of a way to approximate the **sequence** $(r, r, 0, 0, \dots)$ in your metric using sequences with only rational entries? What about the sequence $(r, r, r, 0, \dots)$?

Comment: well if I can find $r'$ some approximation of $r$ (And I can), then the sequence $(r',r',0,0...)$ is an approximation of $(r,r,0,0,...)$ and so on.

Comment: @OriaGruber Yes. Now what if there are *two* different numbers, say $(r, s, 0, 0, \dots)$? Can you approximate that using only rational sequences? What if there were $27$ different numbers?

Comment: I could approximate $(r,s,0,0...)$ using $(r',s',0,0...)$. I could also approximiate $(a_1,a_2,...,a_{27},0,0...)$. So are we talking about the set of sequences that approximate a real number? is that a countable set? Doesn't seem so to me.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/33258/discussion-between-oria-gruber-and-user).

Comment: @OriaGruber So now you should be able to approximate *any* point. The overall space is not countable, but the sequences you're using to approximate (terminating sequences of rational numbers) are a countable set. (But now I think you should spend some time working with this to make sure you understand what exactly the approximation is doing)

Comment: Ah...I get it. I can approximate any point with rational sequences (countable). Countable union of countable sets = countable. And it is a countable union because we have a finite amount of non zero elements.